# Apache Camel Minio Component listObjects operation not working

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, minio

I'm attempting to use the Apache Camel Minio component to manage a simple file cache. To that end, I wrote routes to support all the primary operations such as: getObject, deleteObject, insert... etc. Most operations are working as expected; however, I can't get listObjects to work. For some reason, the message body after running the listObjects operation is an S3Base object containing Minio metadata and the lisObject arguments:

[image: listObjects operation return body]

I do not see this behavior for any of the other Minio operations. I can't find any good examples for this operation and documentation for the Minio component is limited. For the record, there are definitely objects in the test bucket.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ListObjectsTest extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:minioListObjectsTest")
            .routeId("minioListObjectsTest")
            .to("minio://test?operation=listObjects")
            .process(exchange -> {
                var msg = exchange.getMessage();
                var foo = "bar";
            });
    
    }

}
```